# How show local time in New York in PHP?

Tags: javascript, php

I need to display local time in city New Your for everyone user, who visit my web site. How I can do it?

Comment: You would visit php.net and Google. Here, Google this "local time new york php"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Put this at the top of your php.

```
date_default_timezone_set("America/New_York");
```

You can also do this.

```
$date = new DateTime();
$date->setTimezone(new DateTimeZone('America/Detroit'));
$fdate = $date->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');`
```

`$fdate` will print the appropriate time in new york with date.

All the timezones here - http://php.net/manual/en/timezones.america.php